# i want to add gmail accounts to active directory users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hi one of our client they do not have email exchange server they are using emails from third party,So i want to integrate that e-mails for my active directory users.After configuration emails in active directory the SharePoint should take that emails for approval workflows,alerts and every thing as a default user email id.

Answer (score 1):

If you change emails in AD and make userprofile synchronization in central administration then all users emails in sharepoint will be updated. Also check that configure Incoming and Outgoing emails in SharePoint Server for third party email server. See [Use Google Mail as SharePoint Outgoing E-mail](http://nhutcmos.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/use-google-mail-as-sharepoint-outgoing-e-mail/) for more details.

Comment: Hi Andrey thanks for replay.i have one more doubt how to change the email ids of users in active directory.Can you please explain me the total process.

Comment: You can use this [link](http://serverfault.com/a/488832). You must install Install the Active Directory Powershell Module.
Script it like this:

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $email = $user.samaccountname + '@domain.com'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -EmailAddress $email
}